# Java ATM Machine- How do I acess an object(Bank account) from a user input(Enter an account number)

Tags: java, oop

In my Java class we have to create two objects that are supposed to be bank accounts.

Example:

```
Account account1 = new Account();
account1.setName("Isabella");
account1.setBalance(50.00);


Account account2 = new Account();
account2.setName("Oscar");
account2.setBalance(1000.00);
```

My prof wants us to be able to display the information when a user picks an option, like "Account Information". But before that point, the user has to put in an account number, specifically 101 or 102. The problem is that I don't understand how to assign this number in a way that will choose that method.

```
//accesor methods
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
public double getBalance() {
    return this.balance;
}
public double getInterest() {
    return this.interest;
}

//mutator methods
public void setName(String name) {
    String accName = null;
    this.name = accName;
}
public void setBalance(double balance) {
    double accBalance = 0;
    this.balance = accBalance;
}
public void setInterest(double interest) {
    double monthlyInterest = 0;
    this.interest = monthlyInterest;
}
```

These are my accessors and mutators, I don't know if it's related though? My prof said we need to make one for ID(the account number) but to only make an accessor for that one....

Comment: Sounds like you need a `Bank` object that holds the accounts in a `Map` or something like that

Comment: given the level of java being used the prof might expect you to set the account number on creation. That way you have no mutators for it but still have it saved in your object.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? You must have a `Bank` class that contains the accounts, as well as an `ATM` class that interacts with the `Bank` class to retrieve and display the account information.  There's a lot of code missing here.

Answer (score 0):

*Dose your professor told anything about if you can change the  class constructor or not?*
You can change the class constructor of class `Account` as following:

```
Account(int acId)
{
    this.id = acId;
}
```

Then call constructor in your code like:

```
Account account1 = new Account(101);
...
Account account2 = new Account(102);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the account *id* should be **required** and **immutable**.

You'll want to add it to your `Account` constructor, eg

```
public class Account {
    public final int id; // final means this cannot be changed once assigned

    // other fields

    public Account(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // getters, setters, etc
}
```

Now you can get (access) the account id via

```
account1.id
```

---

Some people aren't a fan of `public final` properties so you could always make a *getter* for it

```
public class Account {
    private final int id; 

    // other fields

    public Account(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // getters, setters, etc
}
```

---

As for retrieving accounts by ID, sounds like you need a bank with some sort of map of `id` -> account. For example

```
public class Bank {
    private Map<Integer, Account> accounts = new HashMap<>();

    public void addAccount(final Account account) {
        accounts.put(account.id, account); // or account.getid()
    }

    // using Optional as I cannot stand @Nullable return types
    public Optional<Account> getAccount(final int id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(accounts.get(id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.io.*;

class BankAccount implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String accountNumber;
    private String atmCardNumber;
    private double accountBalance;
    private int atmPin;

    // Constructor
    public BankAccount(String accountNumber, String atmCardNumber, double accountBalance, int atmPin) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.atmCardNumber = atmCardNumber;
        this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
        this.atmPin = atmPin;
    }

    // Getter methods

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public String getAtmCardNumber() {
        return atmCardNumber;
    }

    public double getAccountBalance() {
        return accountBalance;
    }

    public int getAtmPin() {
        return atmPin;
    }

    // Setter methods (if needed)

    public void setAccountBalance(double accountBalance) {
        this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
    }

    // Method to write BankAccount object to a file using serialization
    public void writeToDisk(String filename) {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))) {
            oos.writeObject(this);
            System.out.println("BankAccount information written to disk successfully.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Method to read BankAccount object from a file using deserialization
    public static BankAccount readFromDisk(String filename) {
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) {
            BankAccount account = (BankAccount) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("BankAccount information read from disk successfully.");
            return account;
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Example usage
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creating a BankAccount object
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount("123456789", "987654321", 1000.0, 1234);

        // Writing the BankAccount object to a file
        account.writeToDisk("bank_account_data.ser");

        // Reading the BankAccount object from the file
        BankAccount retrievedAccount = BankAccount.readFromDisk("bank_account_data.ser");

        // Displaying the retrieved account information
        if (retrievedAccount != null) {
            System.out.println("Retrieved Account Information:");
            System.out.println("Account Number: " + retrievedAccount.getAccountNumber());
            System.out.println("ATM Card Number: " + retrievedAccount.getAtmCardNumber());
            System.out.println("Account Balance: " + retrievedAccount.getAccountBalance());
            System.out.println("ATM PIN: " + retrievedAccount.getAtmPin());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should elaborate how your code helps solving the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).